# Where is C:\LOGS file windows but at mac os

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot

I'm a new user on mac os
i want to ask, where is the logs folder like in windows C:\logs but on mac os

thank you, hope your help is useful

Comment: Do you mean /var/log? This is not java related thing

Comment: What kind of logs folder, you are referring to ?

Comment: There's no such directory as C:\LOGS on a standard Windows 10 system anyway. It must be specific to something you've done or you've installed.